# How to add watermark in <iframe> video html5

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel-5

I want to add Watermark in a video using  html5. I am using Laravel 5.7 and plugins Video.js to do this. But when video fullscreen mode, the watermark is not display, But in normal view the watermark displayed.

I got an issue in fullscreen mode, when i click fullscreen video, the watermark is not displayed.

How to fix this issue?

This is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://c.sproutvideo.com/player_api.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://sproutvideo.github.io/sproutvideo-player-api/assets/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="{{asset('video/video-js.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{{asset('css/videojs.watermark.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="{{asset('video/video.js')}}"></script>
  <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "{{asset('video.js/video-js.swf')}}"
  </script>
  <!-- <script src="../videojs.watermark.js"></script> -->
  <!-- For debugging -->
  <script src="{{asset('video/videojs.watermark.js')}}"></script>
  <style>
    p {
      background-color: #eee;
      border: thin solid #777;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>The watermark plugin display an image or text over the video. Give it a shot:</p>

  <iframe id='video_1' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' src='https://videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/709adcb31f19e5c6f8/cd8cf2e796aa69d3' style='width:100%;height:500px;' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>

  <script>
  // initialize video.js
  var my_video_id = videojs('video_1');

  // Set value to the plugin
  my_video_id.watermark({
      file: 'Owned_Stamp.png',
      xpos: 0,
      ypos: 0,
      xrepeat: 0,
      opacity: 0.5
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I noticed you have flash set.  The [documentation](https://github.com/xbgmsharp/videojs-watermark#user-content-known-issues) does state that it doesn't work with a flash fallback.

Comment: Can you share you code for preview at jsfiddle, codepen with watermark image ? I suspect the xpos & ypos setting is the issue. I belive when full screen is triggered these position should be reinitated.